# Wrong SWIFT Code

Tags: international, iban, swift

I sent a wire from the US to France, however I noticed afterwards that my bank put the incorrect SWIFT code, the code they used was for a different branch of the same bank (Literally 3 streets away from the intended bank).

Will the bank realise this and still put the funds in the account or will they look at it and then return the funds to my account?

The IBAN was 100% correct.

Comment: You should contact the French bank.  The answer to this question has, historically, depended on the jurisdiction the bank was in.  If there is a French version of this forum or a parallel forum, I would ask it there.  For example, some US states used to have laws in place that would have prohibited matching up the account.  Each branch was a separate legal entity and though they shared a name, they were isolated institutions.  In fact in some states, since branch banking was illegal, they had to franchise.  My guess is that there will be no problem, but only the French bank knows.

Answer (score 1):

In today's world for most transactions the branch code doesn't matter, except for few investment banking transactions.

The French bank can confirm for sure